# Laravel | Eloquent Populate Foreign Data

Tags: php, mysql, json, laravel, eloquent

I have a database which is set out with a news and a news categories tables.

I have news which has a category 1 which links to a foreign key of the categories table where the category value equals the id in the categories table.

I'm trying to make a controller that gets the category name rather than the category ID when returning the results as a JSON response.

So far I have this inside of a model:

```
public function category()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(NewsCategories::class);
}
```

And then I'm doing this inside of a controller:

```
public function index()
{
    $news = new News();
    $news = $news->category()->get();

    return response()->json(['data' => $news], 200);
}
```

But the JSON response that gets returned is empty. I have googled some things but haven't really found anything useful regarding getting the foreign field which is title within the categories table.

This is the response that I get

```
{
  data: [ ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first issue is that you're under the impression that your new `News` instance has linked categories:

```php
$news = new News();
```

This will yield just an empty model instance; it has no database representation yet. Try fetching categories through a populated model instance:

```php
$news = News::first();

// Or:
$news = News::find(1);
```

and retry the JSON response.

Second issue is that by calling `$news->category()->get()` you're actually [querying the relation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#querying-relations). If you only need to access the title, try `$news->category->title` which will load the associated category record and access the `title` field for you.

---

Regarding your comment, read on [eager/lazy loading](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading).

Comment: With that, it returns the category ID rather than the actual title

Comment: As mentioned previously in the other comment though, `$news = News::with('category')->with('user')->get();` seems to work, is there another way of writing this?

Comment: That's because you're actually [querying](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#querying-relations) the relation model by `$news->category()->get()` instead of accessing the title by `$news->category->title`.

Comment: Doing that, I get trying to get property of none object

Comment: Means that the `$news` instance has no category associated with it to access its `title` field. The output for `News::first()->category->title`?

Comment: The same, trying to get property of none object

Comment: But doing `News::first()->category` returns the value of the field which is 1

Comment: And `News::first()->category()->get()` yields category IDs?

Comment: That brings back nothing :/

Comment: Doing `News::first()->category` brings back the id though

Comment: Adding `return $this->belongsTo(NewsCategories::class, 'id');` seems to have allows `News::first()->category()->get();` to work though

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154569/discussion-between-sepehr-and-tallent123).